# algorithm performance c#

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I want to measure the performance of my code.. if I consider the time as a criterion
I have this code

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2002,7,15);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
// Difference in days.
int differenceInDays = ts.Milliseconds ;
```

Question1: is this the only way that I can test the performance of my algorithm ?
Question2: what are other criterion that C# provide to test the performance? 
Regards

Comment: Use StopWatch as suggested and don't forget to compile in release mode.

Answer (score 3):

Its always better to use [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Check this link for more details. [Performance Tests: Precise Run Time Measurements with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/testing/stopwatch-measure-precise.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class

//Start a stopwatch:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

**//Execute the code**

```
watch.Stop(); //This stops the watch
```

**The elapsed time can be measured by using Elapsed, ElapsedMilliSeconds and ElapsedTicks properties.**

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. It has significantly higher resolution than the DateTime and TimeSpan classes.

Additionally, you can look at the [Windows Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) as a way of measuring performance while your application is running so that you can monitor the health of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a profiler (tool based, for example with [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/)) or [measure the time with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://www.color-of-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95&Itemid=94). It has better precision than the `DateTime` hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to use `DateTime` (because it's easier to use), use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`. It's a little faster (because current date and time are stored in UTC format in Windows) and as an added bonus, you can test your program around the DST change time :-).

But yeah, use `Stopwatch`.

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
watch.Stop()
```

Ah... very important... your code is wrong

```
ts.TotalMilliseconds
```

I did the same error yesterday, but I was measuring times around the second, so it was more difficult to notice :-)